# iOS doesn't recognize and link my apps document type

Tags: ios, xcode, import, info.plist, uti

I've tried deleting the app and cleaning my build. Still nothing... I've reviewed and reviewed but I can't find anything wrong with my code. Why won't iOS recognize my file type and link it to my app? Here is my info.plist and what it looks like in the mail app...

[image: info.plist]
[image: mail view]